# Adaptive payment paypal credentials

Tags: paypal, wordpress-theming

I am working with Project theme in word Press..I this theme i am using Adaptive payment method for paypal gateway..But i am unable to do..Can any one please help me to complete this task. I got an array see below for array..

I am using Sandbox details

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ns3:FaultMessage
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [xmlns:ns3] => http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common
                    [xmlns:ns2] => http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap
                )

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => responseEnvelope
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => timestamp
                        [value] => 2015-10-12T02:10:03.535-07:00
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => ack
                        [value] => Failure
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => correlationId
                        [value] => a7b08f9b701fa
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => build
                        [value] => 17820627
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => error
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => errorId
                        [value] => 520009
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => domain
                        [value] => PLATFORM
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => subdomain
                        [value] => Application
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => severity
                        [value] => Error
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => category
                        [value] => Application
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => message
                        [value] => Account Account not found. Unilateral receiver not allowed in chained payment is restricted
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => parameter
                        [value] => Account not found. Unilateral receiver not allowed in chained payment
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: The problem is i am unable to do payment through paypal